# Why the dedication of the Mishkan and the Temples is not celebrated?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, chagim-holidays

Traditionally we commemorate the destruction of the two Temples, falling on the same day. The dedication of the Mishkan occurred (IIRC) on the first day of Nissan, but the dedication of the first and the second Temples isn't even mentioned, let alone celebrated.

Why is it so? Why don't we celebrate the dedication and hope it will be reestablished soon on the same day?

Comment: I would imagine the incident with Nadab amd Abihu ruled out our commemorating the Chanukat Mishkan

Comment: You don’t celebrate Sukkot? Check out the haftarah in Chul for the second day of Sukkot and Shemini Atzeret

Comment: Re: the dedication of Mishkan, why was this morning the last time to say tachanun for a month?

Comment: And we certainly celebrate the re-dedication of the Second Temple

Comment: Why don't you say Tachanun between Yom Kippur and Sukkot?

Comment: Was the dedication of the second temple exciting? People were crying at how bad it was

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.3.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&qh=%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%94